# Python/Sympy trigonometric solution of cubic equation

Tags: python, sympy, complex-numbers, symbolic-math, equation-solving

Can I get trigonometric symbolic solution of cubic equation using Python/Sympy?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Trigonometric_.28and_hyperbolic.29_method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

update: the solution given below is now available by using the keyword `trig=True` with roots or roots_cubic when solving such an equation.

This form is not given with any keyword I know of, but it is not hard to write a routine to do this:

```
>>> def cutrig(a,b,c,d):
...     a,b,c,d = [S(i) for i in (a,b,c,d)]
...     # x = t - b/3/a
...     p = (3*a*c-b**2)/3/a**2
...     q = (2*b**3-9*a*b*c+27*a**2*d)/(27*a**3)
...     D = 18*a*b*c*d-4*b**3*d+b**2*c**2-4*a*c**3-27*a**2*d**2
...     assert D > 0
...     rv = []
...     for k in range(3):
...         rv.append(2*sqrt(-p/3)*cos(acos(3*q/2/p*sqrt(-3/p))/3-k*2*pi/3))
...     return list(sorted([i - b/3/a for i in rv]))
...
>>> print filldedent(cutrig(-1,2,3,-2))

[-2*sqrt(13)*cos(-acos(8*sqrt(13)/169)/3 + pi/3)/3 + 2/3,
-2*sqrt(13)*sin(-acos(8*sqrt(13)/169)/3 + pi/6)/3 + 2/3, 2/3 +
2*sqrt(13)*cos(acos(8*sqrt(13)/169)/3)/3]
>>>
```

Compared to the default solve solution:

```
>>> print filldedent(solve(-x**3+2*x**2+3*x-2))

[2/3 + (-1/2 - sqrt(3)*I/2)*(8/27 + sqrt(237)*I/9)**(1/3) +
13/(9*(-1/2 - sqrt(3)*I/2)*(8/27 + sqrt(237)*I/9)**(1/3)), 2/3 +
13/(9*(-1/2 + sqrt(3)*I/2)*(8/27 + sqrt(237)*I/9)**(1/3)) + (-1/2 +
sqrt(3)*I/2)*(8/27 + sqrt(237)*I/9)**(1/3), 2/3 + 13/(9*(8/27 +
sqrt(237)*I/9)**(1/3)) + (8/27 + sqrt(237)*I/9)**(1/3)]
```

The values of each are the same:

```
>>> sorted([w.n(2,chop=True) for w in solve(-x**3+2*x**2+3*x-2)])
[-1.3, 0.53, 2.8]
>>> sorted([w.n(2,chop=True) for w in cutrig(-1,2,3,-2)])
[-1.3, 0.53, 2.8]
```

Comment: is it possible to use combination of simplify and solve to figure out exactly the real roots of cubic equation? basically the complex part should cancel out itself.

Comment: See "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function": When a cubic equation has three real roots, the formulas expressing these roots in terms of radicals involve complex numbers. It has been proved that when none of the three real roots is rational—the casus irreducibilis— one cannot express the roots in terms of real radicals. Nevertheless, purely real expressions of the solutions may be obtained using hypergeometric functions,[29] or more elementarily in terms of trigonometric functions, specifically in terms of the cosine and arccosine functions.